# Bootstrap dropdown not closing once I press enter key after selecting option in the dropdown

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code, here I am using dropdown functionality using unordered list.

```
<div class="margin-top-10 pull-right">
  <div class="dropdown pull-right">
    <a tabindex="6" data-toggle="dropdown" class="cursor-pointer dropdown-toggle">
      <span class="Orders-for-Approval">Filter By Team</span>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

    <ul id="eni_header_component_filter_by_team_ul" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <li *ngFor="let group of sharedService.agent.groups" class="text-center">
        <a class="cursor-pointer" tabindex="6" [ngClass]="{'custom-select-dropdown-style':checkSelectedGroup(group)}" (click)="selectedGroupChanged(group);" (keyup.enter)="selectedGroupChanged(group);">{{group.value}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `selectedGroupChanged` is defined as follows:

```
    selectedGroupChanged(group) { 
       this.selectedApprovalQueueStatus = 
       this.definedConstants.MPT_APPROVAL_QUEUE_STATUSES[0]; 
       this.selectedGroupEmit(group,this.selectedApprovalQueueStatu‌​s);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve and what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Thanks, I want to operate dropdown using keyboard keys - tab, enter . I am able to open the dropdown using Down arrow and using enter I can select that option in filter . I want to close this dropdown after pressing enter.

Comment: Can you post the component class code here ?

Comment: This is the only place where dropdown is being used , I am using bootstrap dropdown .

Comment: Actually I meant the code you wrote in typescript, where you have defined the `selectedGroupChanged()` function

Comment: This is the code and it works fine - selectedGroupChanged(group) {
        this.selectedApprovalQueueStatus = this.definedConstants.MPT_APPROVAL_QUEUE_STATUSES[0];
        this.selectedGroupEmit(group,this.selectedApprovalQueueStatus);
    }

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with plunker?